# ScrollView cuts off last object on the page

Tags: react-native

I built a view that is populated dynamically using array mapping.  After doing this, I realized that the View would be too large to contain all the array items on one screen.

Here is my code.

```
            <View style={[styles.flexColumn]}>
                {Characters.map((character, i) =>
                  <View key={i} style={[styles.flexRow]}>
                        <View>
                            <Text>
                                {character.Name}
                            </Text>
                       </View>
                  </View>   
                )}
            </View>
```

So I tried adding a scroll view as the parent like this:

```
    <ScrollView>
                <View style={[styles.flexColumn]}>
                    {Characters.map((character, i) =>
                       <View key={i} style={[styles.flexRow]}>
                            <View>
                                <Text>
                                    {character.Name}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                       </View>  
                   )}
                </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

This does add some scrollability to the view, but it's still cutting off a portion of the last object in the array.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: dhorelik's answer is on point. It could be that you need to add flex: 1, or if there's a component below it, it might be due to the styling of that component overlapping the scrollview. Also, just wanted to mention that you should never use an index as a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScrollView` is intended for showing scrollable content at once. Since you are populating content dynamically, you should be using `FlatList`. Something similar to the following would work:

```js
...
_keyExtractor = character => character.Name

_renderItem = ({character}) => (
    <Text>
        {character.Name}
    </Text>
)

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={Characters}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
    />
  )
}
...
```

Detailed explanation is available [in the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.46/docs/flatlist.html#flatlist).

If you are by any reason still forced to stick to `Scrollview`, the problem is probably related to the styling. I suppose `styles.flexColumn` should be applied to the `ScrollView` itself via `contentContainerStyle`, rather than to its' child `View`.